# Adaptive Server connection failed error in Python/Flask/sqlAlchemy environment with pymssql

Tags: python, flask, sqlalchemy, pymssql

Update: I've confirmed this is only a problem when using an Azure SQL instance.  I can use the same conn string to connect to local, network, and remote SQL (AWS) instances - it is only failing when connecting to Azure.  I can connect to the Azure instance with other tools, like Management Studio.

I am building a small Python(3.4.x)/Flask application.  I'm a complete noob here so forgive me if I break any rules in posting.

I have created the database engine with:

```
from sqlalchemy import create_engine
from sqlalchemy.orm import scoped_session, sessionmaker
from sqlalchemy.ext.declarative import declarative_base

engine = create_engine('mssql+pymssql://dbadmin:dbadminpass@somedomain.server.net/databasename?charset=utf8')
db_session = scoped_session(sessionmaker(autocommit = False, autoflush = False, bind = engine))

Base = declarative_base()
Base.query = db_session.query_property()

def init_db():
    import models
    Base.metadata.creat_all(bind=engine)
```

Everything builds/interprets correctly at runtime but I get an error on running the query:

```
usr = User.query.filter_by(username=form.user.data).first()
```

The error is:

```
sqlalchemy.exc.OperationalError: (OperationalError) (20002, b'DB-Lib error message 20002, severity 9:\nAdaptive Server connection failed\n') None None
```

packages are: Flask==0.10.1,  pymssql==2.1.1,  SQLAlchemy==0.9.8

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Have you done some research on that error message? If so - why were the results unsatisfactory (so we don't duplicate your effort)?

Comment: Yes, thank you.  Everything I have found seems to center around a freeTDS version problem, however, I'm not sure that it relates (other than it gives the same error message).  My understanding is that freeTDS is a set of librarys for *nix boxes to allow them to speak MS SQL server.  I am developing, testing, and deploying the app to Windows based environment(s).

Comment: do you have your C:\freetds.conf file. see http://pymssql.org/en/latest/freetds.html

Comment: the freetds.conf file is:
 [global]
    port = 1433
    tds version = 7.0

Is there a way to set this in the app.config file?  I am deploying this to Azure and need a way to include this in the app config rather than a location on the hard drive.

Comment: Even I'm facing the same problem with pymssql. Tried pyodbc, but its installation itself is failing on azure. Were you able to fix this issue?

Answer (score 0):

I had similar problem and solved it by explicitly setting `tds version = 7.0`. FreeTDS reads the user's `${HOME}/.freetds.conf` before resorting to the system-wide `sysconfdir/freetds.conf`. So, I created `~/.freetds.conf` with `[global]` section as:

```
[global]
tds version = 7.0
```

You can find more information on `freetds.con`: http://www.freetds.org/userguide/freetdsconf.htm

Answer (score 0):

As I just had the same problem.

Since I could get [`pymssql`](http://www.pymssql.org/en/latest/azure.html) to connect bypassing `sqlalchemy`, I figured everything else should be fine, so I used the `create_engine` parameter [`connect_args`](http://docs.sqlalchemy.org/en/latest/core/engines.html?highlight=create_engine#sqlalchemy.create_engine.params.connect_args) to pass everything straight to `pymssql.connect`.

```
server_name = "sql_server_name"
server_addres = server_name + ".database.windows.net"
database = "database_name"
username = "{}@{}".format("my_username", server_name)
password = "strong_password"

arguments = dict(server=server_addres, user=username,
                                 password=password, database=database, charset="utf8")

AZURE_ENGINE = create_engine('mssql+pymssql:///', connect_args=arguments)
```

This works fine and does not require one to meddle with the `.freetds.conf` file at all.

Also, note that `pymssql` requires usernname to be in the form `username@servername`. For more information see the linked documentation.